# \box_new:N for use with \hbox_set:Nn

Tags: boxes, expl3, latex3

My question is regarding `\l_tmpa_box`. Consider the following code:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \includegraphics[scale=0.125]{images/shc_logo.pdf} } 

\dim_new:N \l__shc_logo_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l__shc_logo_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

If I use the code above, the dimension is stored correctly. Is it possible to have something like `\l_shc_tmpa_box`?

I would like something like:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\hbox_set:Nn \l_shc_tmpa_box { \includegraphics[scale=0.125]{images/shc_logo.pdf} } 

\dim_new:N \l__shc_logo_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l__shc_logo_dim { \box_wd:N \l_shc_tmpa_box }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

But this does not compile and gives an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \l_shc_tmpa_box
l.10 ...aphics[scale=0.125]{images/shc_logo.pdf} }
```

I was looking the L3 documentation but did not find how to create a new `hbox`.

Is it ok to use `\box_new:N \l_shc_tmpa_box`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a box register can be used to store either an `hbox` or a `vbox`.  At the very beginning of `l3box` in `interface3.pdf` there is this paragraph:

> There are three kinds of box operations: horizontal mode denoted with prefix `\hbox_`,
> vertical mode with prefix `\vbox_`, and the generic operations working in both modes with
> prefix `\box_`.

which means that `\box_new:N` works with either mode, so this is correct:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_shc_tmpa_box
\hbox_set:Nn \l_shc_tmpa_box { \includegraphics[scale=0.125]{images/shc_logo.pdf} } 

\dim_new:N \l__shc_logo_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l__shc_logo_dim { \box_wd:N \l_shc_tmpa_box }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Just for completeness, if later you want to find out if a box is a horizontal or a vertical box you can use `\box_if_horizontal:NTF` or `\box_if_vertical:NTF`, or if it is empty with `\box_if_empty:NTF`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind recommendations. Amazing information.